# Nonuniform sampling for 2D image in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy, computer-vision

I have a 2D image that can be represented as a Numpy array in Python. I need to downsample this image in a way that downsampling happens more at the sides and less at the center. To be more specific, let's say downsampling with rate 2 at the center, 4 at the borders, and something in between (relative to the distance to the center) on other points. In other words, I am looking for the `nonUniformDownsample` function in the code below:

```
img = cv2.imread("flower.jpg") 
img_focused = nonUniformDownsample(image=img, centerVal=2, borderVal=4)
```

Comment: You could resample it using [scipy.interpolate.griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html), and then use the result to draw the nre image you want maybe?

Comment: I can't imagine how. this function only does interpolation. and what is nre image. Can you explain more?

Comment: Interpolating it over the whole region will allow you to find the average pixel colour for each of the new ones without having to do some kind of horrible geometry madness. Alternatively you could pixelate the whole image, and stitch them together with smaller masks for the higher detailed images close to the centre.

Comment: You mean for example downsample the image with rates 2, 3, and 4. Then Merge them manually using masks? I don't find it straightforward to implement, and I think it may cause artifacts. I was hoping to find something more natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand your question/goal, but as will commented `scipy.interpolate.griddata` should work. You could use something like this:

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,100), np.linspace(-1,1,100))
A = np.sin(9.5*pi*X) + np.sin(9.5*np.pi*Y)
```

Here `A` looks like this:

[image]

```
n = 50
X_, Y_ = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,n), np.linspace(-1,1,n))
X_ = (3*X_**3 + X_) / 4
Y_ = (3*Y_**3 + Y_) / 4

x = np.dstack((X,Y)).reshape((100*100, 2))
xi = np.dstack((X_,Y_)).reshape((n*n, 2))
A_ = griddata(x, A.flat, xi, method='cubic')
```

And `A_` looks like this:

[image]